# Android Studio Emulator fails at startup with "VCPU Shutdown Request"

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, haxm

Android Studio Emulator fails at startup with "VCPU Shutdown Request"

I have a new installation of Android Studio Flamingo 2022.2.1 Patch 1
Running under Windows 10 with a Core I7 860 processor
Emulator version is 32.1.12
HAXM version is 7.6.5
There is 70 GB of disk space available

Attempts to start an emulator always fail with the log file showing a "VCPU Shutdown Request".  There are no apparent errors preceding the shutdown,

I have tried reinstalling Android Studio and HAXM.  I have tried different device emulations, all with X86_64 images. There are various posts on-line regarding this problem although most are fairly old (2016) and relate to previous bugs in HAXM.  This is what shows in the "idea.log" file:

```
2023-05-21 19:35:49,700 [ 327715]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 33 - C:\Users\JimAndVal\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -no-snapshot-load -avd Pixel_6_API_33 -qt-hide-window -grpc-use-token -idle-grpc-timeout 300
2023-05-21 19:35:49,740 [ 327755]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 33 - Android emulator version 32.1.12.0 (build_id 9751036) (CL:N/A)
2023-05-21 19:35:49,741 [ 327756]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 33 - Found systemPath C:\Users\JimAndVal\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-33\google_apis\x86_64\
2023-05-21 19:35:50,451 [ 328466]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 33 - Warning: Quick Boot / Snapshots not supported on this machine. A CPU with EPT + UG features is currently needed. We will address this in a future release.
2023-05-21 19:35:50,467 [ 328482]   WARN - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 33 - Not all modern X86 virtualization features supported, which introduces problems with slowdown when running Android on multicore vCPUs. Setting AVD to run with 1 vCPU core only.
2023-05-21 19:35:51,167 [ 329182]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 33 - Storing crashdata in: C:\Users\JIMAND~1\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash.db, detection is enabled
2023-05-21 19:35:51,167 [ 329182]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 33 - Duplicate loglines will be removed, if you wish to see each indiviudal line launch with the -log-nofilter flag.
2023-05-21 19:35:51,167 [ 329182]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 33 - IPv4 server found: 192.168.1.1
2023-05-21 19:35:51,167 [ 329182]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 33 - RegGetValueW failed 2 The system cannot find the file specified.
2023-05-21 19:35:51,167 [ 329182]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 33 - 
2023-05-21 19:35:51,167 [ 329182]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 33 - added library vulkan-1.dll
2023-05-21 19:35:51,168 [ 329183]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 33 - Sending adb public key [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 @unknown]
2023-05-21 19:35:51,168 [ 329183]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 33 - HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
2023-05-21 19:35:51,897 [ 329912]   INFO - #c.a.t.i.d.v.VirtualDeviceChangeListener - emulator-5554 connected
2023-05-21 19:35:51,902 [ 329917]   WARN - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 33 - *** Basic token auth will be deprecated soon, please migrate to using -grpc-use-jwt ***
2023-05-21 19:35:51,904 [ 329919]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 33 - Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554, security: Local, auth: +token
2023-05-21 19:35:51,904 [ 329919]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 33 - Advertising in: C:\Users\JimAndVal\AppData\Local\Temp\avd\running\pid_20904.ini
2023-05-21 19:35:51,946 [ 329961]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 33 - Setting display: 0 configuration to: 1080x2400, dpi: 420x420
2023-05-21 19:35:52,224 [ 330239]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 33 - VCPU shutdown request
2023-05-21 19:35:52,224 [ 330239]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 33 - Deleting snapshot default_boot
2023-05-21 19:35:53,746 [ 331761]   WARN - #c.a.t.i.s.e.EmulatorController - Unable to connect Pixel 6 API 33 (5554)
2023-05-21 19:35:54,554 [ 332569]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 API 33 - Process finished with exit code 0
2023-05-21 19:35:54,774 [ 332789]   INFO - #c.a.t.i.d.v.VirtualDeviceChangeListener - emulator-5554 disconnected
2023-05-21 19:35:54,774 [ 332789]   INFO - #c.a.t.i.a.p.ProcessNameMonitor - Removing emulator-5554: 1375856283
2023-05-21 19:35:58,070 [ 336085]   INFO - #c.i.i.b.BookmarkManager - no state loaded for old bookmarks
2023-05-21 19:35:58,082 [ 336097]   INFO - #c.i.i.f.FavoritesManager - no state loaded for old favorites
2023-05-21 19:36:03,899 [ 341914]   INFO - #c.i.i.a.RevealFileAction - Exit code 1
2023-05-21 19:36:08,155 [ 346170]   INFO - #c.i.c.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving appFileTypeManager took 32 ms
2023-05-21 19:36:08,197 [ 346212]   INFO - #c.i.c.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving Project(name=My Application, containerState=COMPONENT_CREATED, componentStore=D:\Users\JimAndVal\Documents\JIM\Android Development\MyApplication)KotlinCommonCompilerArguments took 19 ms
```

Everything looks good to me until the "VCPU shutdown request".  I would appreciate any insights into this problem,

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.